# Add 1 to current year with function TODAY()

Tags: excel, function, date

I have cell B3 configured with date format and the table as follows

[image]

What I want to do is that, having the cell format as date, if the month in cell A2 is JANUARY, B2 shows 2023 (that is, it adds 1 to the current year, but instead it returns 1/14/1900 and I don't know how to fix it, what can I do?

```
=IF(A2="JANUARY";TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy")+1;TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy"))
```

Comment: Try `=IF(A2="JANUARY",YEAR(TODAY())+1,TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy"))`

Comment: Don't format the cell as a date since 2023 is not a date. You could also use: `=YEAR(TODAY())+(A2="JANUARY")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to know about the `EDATE()` Excel function, which adds one or several months to a start date, as you can see here:

[image]

Once you have that result, you can use the `=YEAR()` function in order to find the year of the date.

Comment: How does this function applied to the example work?